# x is not associated to x! Error in sequelize-typescript

Tags: sql-server, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I want to join the same table, but it doesn't work.

This is my raw query

```
SELECT A.user_nm, B.user_nm, C.user_nm
FROM AUT_USER_TB A
LEFT JOIN AUT_USER_TB B ON A.uid = B.created_uid
LEFT JOIN AUT_USER_TB C ON A.uid = C.updated_uid
```

This is my sequelize code

```
public read = async() => {
    try {
      const result = await this.repo.findAll(
        { 
          include: [
            {
              model: sequelize.models.AutUser,
            }
          ],
        });

      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
```

This is ModelDefinition

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'AUT_USER_TB',
  modelName: 'AutUser',
  paranoid: true,
  timestamps: true,
  underscored: true,
})
export default class AutUser extends Model<IAutUser> {
  @Column({
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  uid: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'BINARY(16)',
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: () => Buffer.from(uuid(), 'hex'),
  })
  get uuid() : string {
    return Buffer.from(this.getDataValue('uuid') as any).toString('hex'); 
  };

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING(20),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  id: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => AutGroup)
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
  })
  group_id: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  user_nm: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING(100),
  })
  pwd: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  })
  email: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.TINYINT,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 1,
  })
  pwd_fg: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.TINYINT,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 0,
  })
  admin_fg: number;

  @CreatedAt
  @Column({
    type: DataType.DATE,
    allowNull: false
  })
  created_at: Date;
  
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  created_uid: number;

  @UpdatedAt
  @Column({
    type: DataType.DATE,
    allowNull: false
  })
  updated_at: Date;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  updated_uid: number;

  @DeletedAt
  @Column({
    type: DataType.DATE,
  })
  deleted_at: Date;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
  })
  deleted_uid: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => AutGroup, { foreignKey: 'group_id', onDelete: 'no action', onUpdate: 'cascade' })
  autGroup: AutGroup;
}
```

This is Error Description

> Error :  EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: AutUser is not associated to AutUser!
> at Function._getIncludedAssociation (D:\00_SVN\RnD_Project\mes_server\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:710:13)
> at Function._validateIncludedElement (D:\00_SVN\RnD_Project\mes_server\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:614:53)
> at D:\00_SVN\RnD_Project\mes_server\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:509:37
> at Array.map ()
> at Function._validateIncludedElements (D:\00_SVN\RnD_Project\mes_server\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:504:39)
> at Function.findAll (D:\00_SVN\RnD_Project\mes_server\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1723:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
> expose: false,
> statusCode: 500,
> status: 500

I want to join and use the AutUser table and another AutUser table.

When I run the code above, an error like this appeared. "AutUser is not associated to AutUser!"

I really need your help.

Comment: This seems identical to a question I saw earlier? You shouldn't delete and repost the same question.

Comment: The question includes the T-SQL of the raw query you wish to perform, but not the code that calls `await sequelize.query(...)` with it? Please edit your question to include that.